# Unable to set RDS timeouts, Server 2012/2016

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, group-policy, windows-server-2016, rds

Experiencing unable to set timeouts and logoff times in GPO for Windows RDS Server 2012 and 2016.

Working with 2008 this works fine but the same settings do not get applied on 2012/2016.

Looked at the registry but this also fails and does not work.

Any ideas where this can be fix/applied.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to manage these timeouts with Server Manager instead:

in Remote Desktop Services, go to your `Collection Properties -> Session` tab, and change the values of

- End a disconnected session
- Active session limit
- Idle session limit

[image: 1]]

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the reply. I need to manage this centrally on a GPO manually is not a option.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out, was combination of GPO's and registry keys but not in the usual place.